# Access command line parameters in C++ Windows App

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder, rad-studio

I have a C++ Windows App written in Embarcadero C++Builder, and I would like to pass the arguments given in the command prompt to the application.

```cpp
int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR argv, int argc)
{
    try
    {
        Application->Initialize();
        Application->CreateForm(__classid(TFormMain), &FormMain);
        if (argc > 1)
        {
            // pass argv to app.
        }
        Application->Run();
    }
    catch (Exception &exception)
    {
        Application->ShowException(&exception);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        try
        {
            throw Exception("");
        }
        catch (Exception &exception)
        {
            Application->ShowException(&exception);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: IIRC `Application->ExeName` contains path, filename and all the parameters in form of string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, the last 2 parameters of your `_tWinMain` entry point are wrong.  They are actually defined as `LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd` instead.  `argv`/`argc` parameters are provided only in a console app's `main()`-style entry point, not in a GUI app's `WinMain`-style entry point.  The `lpCmdLine` parameter is a pointer to a single string containing the entire raw command-line, it is not pre-parsed into an array of substrings, like `main()` does.  And the `nShowCmd` parameter is not related to the command-line at all.

You can use the Win32 API [`GetCommandLineW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew) and [`CommandLineToArgvW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) functions to get such an array.

Alternatively, C++Builder's RTL has several [Command Line Support Routines](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Command_Line_Support_Routines) of its own:

- [`System::CmdLine`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.CmdLine)
- [`System::ParamCount()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamCount)
- [`System::ParamStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamStr)
- [`System::Sysutils::FindCmdLineSwitch()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FindCmdLineSwitch)